# PySpark: Column Is Not Iterable

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, typeerror

I have Spark dataframe as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F

df = spark.sql("SELECT transaction_id, transaction_label, module_name, length(transaction_label) as length FROM all_trans")
df.show()

+---------------+-----------------+-----------+------+
| transaction_id|transaction_label|module_name|length|
+---------------+-----------------+-----------+------+
|0P2117292543428|              EDU|        mcc|     3|
| 0P211729824944|              EDU|        mcc|     3|
|  0P31172950208|              EDU|        mcc|     3|
|0P2117294027213|       FUN0402007|      regex|    10|
|0P2117294027213|            FUN04|        mcc|     5|
|0P2117293581427|       FUN0402007|      regex|    10|
|0P2117293581427|            FUN04|        mcc|     5|
|0P2117292967336|       FUN0402007|      regex|    10|
|0P2117292967336|            FUN04|        mcc|     5|
|0P2117292659416|       FUN0402007|      regex|    10|
|0P2117292659416|            FUN04|        mcc|     5|
|0P2117293159304|       FUN0402007|      regex|    10|
|0P2117293159304|            FUN04|        mcc|     5|
|0P2117293237687|       FUN0402007|      regex|    10|
|0P2117293237687|            FUN04|        mcc|     5|
|0P2117293548610|       FUN0402007|      regex|    10|
|0P2117293548610|            FUN04|        mcc|     5|
|0P2117293678239|       FUN0402007|      regex|    10|
|0P2117293678239|            FUN04|        mcc|     5|
|0P2117293840924|       FUN0402007|      regex|    10|
+---------------+-----------------+-----------+------+
```

I want to compare `transaction_label` of the same `transaction_id` for different `module_name`.

I tried:

```
df = (df.filter("module_name = 'mcc'").alias('m')
    .join(df.filter("module_name = 'regex'").alias('r'), 'transaction_id')
    .withColumn('check', F.col('m.transaction_label') == F.substring('r.transaction_label', 1, F.col('m.length')))
)
df.show()
```

which has yielded:

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd argument in `substring` expects a number, but you provided a column instead.

Switch to SQL when using `substring`. SQL can deal with this situation.

```py
df = (df.filter("module_name = 'mcc'").alias('m')
    .join(df.filter("module_name = 'regex'").alias('r'), 'transaction_id')
    .withColumn('check', F.col('m.transaction_label') == F.expr("substring(r.transaction_label, 1, m.length)"))
)
```

Comment: I'm getting:  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'm.transaction_label' is ambiguous, could be: m.transaction_label, m.transaction_label.

Comment: First, I was getting the above on "module_name"...

Comment: Do you use more joins after you give the name `m` to dataframe? For subsequent self joins you should give new names.

Comment: Nope. I'm trying to cope around with "withColumnRenamed" now

Comment: Apparently your `m` dataframe has 2 columns with the same name

Comment: Yes. Trying to rename them now. Didn't now the SQL API can get so confused with it.

Comment: Do you use both names? `m` and `r`?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this could happen due to operator precedence ambiguity in join conditions. Make sure to explicitly enclose individual conditional statements and then only use &, |, etc.

Example is given below of correct expression.

```
result_df = df1.alias('df1').join(df2_broadcast.alias('df2_broadcast'),
                                  (     (F.col('df1.a') == F.col('df2_broadcast.x'))
                                            &
                                        (F.col('df1.b_timestmp') < F.col('df2_broadcast.y_timestmp'))
                                   ),"right")
```