# Does using PySpark "functions.expr()" have a performance impact on query?

Tags: dataframe, performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The `functions.expr("[SQL]")` can be used as an alternative way to query in so many cases, for instance:

```py
df2=df.withColumn("gender", expr("CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 'Male' " +
           "WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 'Female' ELSE 'unknown' END"))
```

which is equal to

```py
df2=df.withColumn("gender", when(col("gender") == "M", "Male")
                           .when(col("gender") == "F", "Female")
                           .otherwise("Unknown")
```

I am wondering, does it have a performance difference?

And what about the following example (which functions API doesn't have an out-of-box solution to add hours)?

```py
df = df.withColumn('testing_time', df.testing_time + expr('INTERVAL 2 HOURS'))
```

VS

```py
df = df.withColumn("testing_time", (unix_timestamp("testing_time") + 7200).cast('timestamp'))
```

Finally, do you suggest to use `functions.expr` where ever it could be?

Comment: Hey, see this question, i believe it is same case in different contexts, because the interpreter is different but execution engine is same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222539/spark-sql-queries-vs-dataframe-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- > does it have a performance difference?

  No, both versions are identic in every aspect, including performance.

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  df = spark.createDataFrame([("M",), ("F",)], ["gender"])

  df2 = df.withColumn("gender", F.when(F.col("gender") == "M", "Male")
                                 .when(F.col("gender") == "F", "Female")
                                 .otherwise("Unknown"))

  df3 = df.withColumn("gender", F.expr("CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 'Male' " +
                                            "WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 'Female' ELSE 'Unknown' END"))
  ```

  PySpark code doesn't directly make Spark run the algorithm. It creates logical and physical plans which actually  run the algorithm. You can inspect them and compare - they are identic.

  ```py
  df2.explain()
  # == Physical Plan ==
  # *(1) Project [CASE WHEN (gender#49 = M) THEN Male WHEN (gender#49 = F) THEN Female ELSE Unknown END AS gender#51]
  # +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[gender#49]

  df3.explain()
  # == Physical Plan ==
  # *(1) Project [CASE WHEN (gender#49 = M) THEN Male WHEN (gender#49 = F) THEN Female ELSE Unknown END AS gender#53]
  # +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[gender#49]

  df2.sameSemantics(df3)  # Available in Spark 3.1+
  # True
  ```
- Regarding the use of `expr`, use it

  - when you don't have an equivalent in PySpark
  - when your Spark version doesn't yet support PySpark equivalent
  - when PySpark function expects a value, but you want to provide a column (e.g. [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73622372/pyspark-column-is-not-iterable/73622887))

  Otherwise, it often looks cleaner when written in PySpark.